# VBA - copy/insert a row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy an entire row but I'd like to add it to the very top of another worksheet pushing the existing content one row down. I've merged the following code from some other questions in SO. It works find but, as one would expect, it replaces the content of the first row in the target worksheet. How would I insert it to the top of the target worksheet so it pushes everything else down.

```
Sub CopyHeader()
Dim sw As Worksheet: Set sw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OriginalFunding") 'source worksheet
Dim tw As Worksheet: Set tw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FundingReturn") 'target worksheet
Const WHAT_TO_FIND As String = "Learner"

            Set FoundCell = sw.Range("A:A").Find(What:=WHAT_TO_FIND)
            If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                sw.Rows(FoundCell.Row).EntireRow.Copy tw.Range("A1")

            Else
                MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " not found")
            End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You could first insert a blank row and the copy to it.

Comment: Good thinking. Done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Insert Shift

### 'Object References Not Allowed' Version

```
Sub CopyHeader()

  Const cSrc As String = "OriginalFunding"  ' Source Worksheet
  Const cTgt As String = "FundingReturn"    ' Target Worksheet
  Const cSrcRng As String = "A:A"           ' Source Range
  Const cTgtRng As String = "A1"            ' Target Range
  Const cSearch As String = "Learner"       ' Search String

  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cSrc)
    If Not .Range(cSrcRng).Find(What:=cSearch) Is Nothing Then
      .Range(cSrcRng).Find(What:=cSearch).EntireRow.Copy
      .Parent.Worksheets(cTgt).Range(cTgtRng).Insert (xlShiftDown)
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
     Else
      MsgBox "'" & cSearch & "' not found."
    End If
  End With

End Sub
```